# Select Record Whose Status Value Same When Repeat

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql server query in this query I just want to fetch all accounts where its status is same, According to my query the record could repeat with different status, What I want to fetch is select all accounts whose status is same.

Acctually we search customer based on nic given sample **(3120000000000)** then he could have more than 1 account and any account from these could be linked from another nic then i have to select those accounts whose nic status in bvs is **00**.

In this sample account **2001111111** is joint with **3120000000000** and **3120000000001** so this account repeat in result because its bvs status is **00** for  **3120000000000** but **01** for **3120000000001** so this record should not appear in select.

**Example**

```
select distinct  result.AccountID,bvs.BVSResult from (
select  distinct AccountID, REPLACE(NIC,'-','') AS NIC from [dbo]. 
[t_account] where AccountID IN 
(
 SELECT AccountID FROM  [dbo].[t_account]  where REPLACE(NIC,'-','')  
 =REPLACE('3120000000000','-','')
)

) as result inner join [BVSCheck] as bvs on REPLACE(result.NIC,'-','') = 
REPLACE(bvs.Cnic,'-','')
```

**Result**

```
2001111111  01
2006111111  00
2001111111  00
2006111111  00
```

Here records like

> 2001111111   00

and

> 2001111111    01

should not select because its status is changing the status should be **00**

**Require Result**

```
 2006111111 00

 2006111111 00
```

**Sample Data BVS**

```
nic = 3120000000000 acc = 2001111111 bvs = 00

nic = 3120000000001 acc = 2001111111 bvs = 01
```

**Sample Data Account**

```
nic = 3120000000000  acc = 2001111111 
nic = 3120000000000  acc = 2006111112
nic = 3120000000000  acc = 2006111113

nic = 3120000000001  acc = 2006111111
```

I have tried [ALL](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-all/) query but its not working in my scenario.

Please help.

Comment: Please post some sample data aswell

Comment: @DawoodAwan sample result is given

Comment: Sample input data..

Comment: will you only ever have 2 status? i.e. 00 and 01?

Comment: yes exactly only 2

Comment: I still don't get it. You have an account table (with four sample accounts 2001111111, 2006111111, 2006111112, 2006111113). Each account is assigned to one customer (nic). You have a BVS table that lists accounts and customers, where the pairs may or may not exist in the accounts table. Now what exactly are you looking for? You select all accounts of customer 3120000000000. Result = accounts 2001111111, 2006111112, 2006111113. Then you say you want to look up these accounts in the BVS table with BVS 00. This leads to a single customer 3120000000000 (for account 2001111111)...

Comment: ... Then, however, you say you also want to know whether the same account has a BVS 01 in the table and exclude it from the results, if this is the case. According to the description you would want to see accounts 2001111111, 2006111112, 2006111113 minus 2001111111 = accounts 2006111112, 2006111113. But your expected result shown is 2006111111, which is even the only account that never played a role in any of the above mentioned rules. And for some reson you want to select it twice, both times with a number 00 (a BVS?). Please edit your request and clarify what you want to select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `CROUP BY .. HAVING` to your query

```
SELECT result.AccountID, max(bvs.BVSResult) 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT AccountID, REPLACE(NIC,'-','') AS NIC 
    FROM [dbo].[t_account] 
    WHERE AccountID IN (
         SELECT AccountID 
         FROM  [dbo].[t_account]  
         WHERE REPLACE(NIC,'-','') ='3120000000000'
    )
) result 
JOIN [BVSCheck] bvs ON REPLACE(result.NIC,'-','') = REPLACE(bvs.Cnic,'-','') 
GROUP BY result.AccountID
HAVING count(distinct bvs.BVSResult) = 1
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=f46058c732ef2271dbe0440bc8a3512d) based on "Sample Data BVS" and "Sample Data Account"

Comment: there is an exception 'BVSCheck.BVSResult' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I've checked,  `max(bvs.BVSResult)`  - it is contained  in  an aggregate function. Provide sample input data to check the query with.

Comment: please check out the sample data

Comment: Added fiddle to the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for NICs where all accounts have the same status, then you can use window functions:

```
select ab.*
from (select a.*,
             min(b.BVSResult) over (partition by replace(a.NIC, '-', '')) as min_BVSResult,
             max(b.BVSResult) over (partition by replace(a.NIC, '-', '')) as max_BVSResult,
      from [dbo].[t_account] a join
           [BVSCheck] b
           on replace(a.NIC, '-', '') = 
replace(b.Cnic, '-', '') 
     ) ab
where min_BVSResult = max_BVSResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this query:

```
Select AccountID, BVSResult from Table
Group by AccountID, BVSResult
Having Count (Distinct BVSResult) = 1 and count(AccountID) > 1
```

Comment: prawan this wont work acctually we search customer based on nic then he could have more than 1 accounts and any account from these could be linked from another nic then i have to select those accounts whose nic is status is bvs is 00

Comment: can you please share the raw data and required output where this query will not work for your desired output.